# show '-' instead of 0 in sql select

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get `'-'` instead of 0 when the value i am selecting is equal to 0.

`Qa01` field is a string. (I have to cast it to Integer for the SUM function)

here i tried this :

```
SELECT [Code article],
       Division,
       count(LigneFab),
       IIF(sum(cast(Qa01 as int))='0','-',sum(cast(Qa01 as int))) as qa01
from   dbo.PDP 
where  [Code article] = '10000100510' 
and    Division = '1000'
group by [Code article],
         Division
```

If Qa01 value is '10' it's displaying '10' but if the value is '0', it's displaying '0' instead of '-' so my query is not working..

Is there a way to display '-' instead of '0' ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help,

here is the solution that's working for me :

```
SELECT [Code article],Division,count(LigneFab),
(CASE (CASE cast(sum(cast(Qa01 as int)) as nvarchar(50))
WHEN '0' 
   THEN '-'
   ELSE (CASE cast(sum(cast(Qa01 as int)) as nvarchar(50)) END) as Qa01
from dbo.PDP where [Code article] = '10000100510' and Division = '1000'
group by [Code article],Division
```

i had to convert back in nvarchar the sum of Qa01, so it's displaying '-' when Qa01 = '0' as i wanted.

Comment: You should specify the length of your nvarchar. When you don't specify the length it uses a default. And to make things interesting the default length can be different depending on the usage.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing to the string `'0'` instead of the number `0`

Change it to

```
IIF(sum(cast(Qa01 as int)) = 0,'-',sum(cast(Qa01 as int))) as qa01
```

Comment: i tried your solution and replaced '-' by 'tt' and it give me this error :  "Failed converting the varchar value 'tt' in int data type."

Comment: The output is going to be an int type - so you'll need to cast it back to a char - `cast(sum(cast(Qa01 as char(X)))) as int)` (where X is the length of the char type you need)

Answer (score 1):

You need to be careful with your types.  For instance you have `0` in single quotes, which is not necessary.

```
   (CASE WHEN sum(cast(Qa01 as int)) = 0 THEN
         ELSE CAST(sum(cast(Qa01 as int)) as VARCHAR(32))
    END) as qa01
```

Notes:

- You should be explicit about your type conversions.
- Whenever you use any of the character types in SQL Server, *always* include a length.  The length varies by context, which can introduce unexpected errors.
- `CASE` is the ANSI standard for conditional expressions.  `IIF()` is for backwards compatibility to MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

use [case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) -

```
(case(Convert(Varchar,sum(Qa01)) when '0' then '-' else Convert(Varchar,sum(Qa01)) end) as qa01
```